# Price filtering ascending & descending React js

Tags: reactjs, sorting, filtering

I tried to set up the functionality to filter my product in an ascending or descending manner.

If you check my code below in order to access the price of each product I tried to map through the products, remove then the dollar sign and sort it to ascending and finally set the new state of the products.

But now I feel confused now because I have the sorted array but no more the entire product when trying to set the new state of the product ??

Thank you for helping

```
const data = [
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$49.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Football",
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$9.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Baseball",
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$29.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "Basketball",
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$99.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "iPod Touch",
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$399.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "iPhone 5",
  },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7" },
];

export default data;

const App = () => {
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");
  const [productsInfo, setProductsInfo] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const selectedChangeFilter = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === "sporting goods") {
      const sportingGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Sporting Goods"
      );
      setProductsInfo(sportingGoods);
    }
    if (e.target.value === "electronics") {
      const electronicsGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Electronics"
      );
      setProductsInfo(electronicsGoods);
    }
    if (e.target.value === "lowest price") {
      const lowestPriceGoods = data
        .map((product) => product.price.substr(1))
        .sort((a, b) => a - b);
      console.log(lowestPriceGoods);
      setProductsInfo(lowestPriceGoods);
    }
    if (e.target.value === "all") {
      setProductsInfo(data);
    }
  };

  const searchProducts = (products) => {
    if (searchValue.toLowerCase().trim() === "") {
      setProductsInfo(products);
    } else {
      const seekedItem = productsInfo.filter(
        (product) =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue) ||
          product.category.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)
      );
      setProductsInfo(seekedItem);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchInput
        handleChange={handleChange}
        searchValue={searchValue}
        selectedChangeFilter={selectedChangeFilter}
      />
      <Products
        data={data}
        searchValue={searchValue}
        productsInfo={productsInfo}
        searchProducts={searchProducts}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: can you share your code in codesandbox?

Comment: here is the code on codesandbox @akhtarvahid  https://codesandbox.io/s/bw6sl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this improved code

```
 const selectedChangeFilter = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    if (value === "sporting goods") {
      const sportingGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Sporting Goods"
      );
      setProductsInfo(sportingGoods);
    }
    if (value === "electronics") {
      const electronicsGoods = data.filter(
        (product) => product.category === "Electronics"
      );
      setProductsInfo(electronicsGoods);
    }
    if (value === "lowest price") {
      const lowestPriceGoods = data.sort((el1,el2) => el1.price.localeCompare(el2.price, undefined, {numeric: true}));
      setProductsInfo([...lowestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "highest price") {
      const highestPriceGoods = data.sort((el1,el2) => el2.price.localeCompare(el1.price, undefined, {numeric: true}));
      setProductsInfo([...highestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "all") {
      setProductsInfo(data);
    }
  };
```

Comment: First time I heard about the method localCompare(). Very interesting method. Thanks a lot for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string#localeCompare` to sort your array based on the number by using `numeric` property.

```js
const data = [ { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$49.99", stocked: true, name: "Football", }, { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$9.99", stocked: true, name: "Baseball", }, { category: "Sporting Goods", price: "$29.99", stocked: false, name: "Basketball",}, { category: "Electronics", price: "$99.99", stocked: true, name: "iPod Touch", }, { category: "Electronics", price: "$399.99", stocked: false, name: "iPhone 5", }, { category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7" }, ];

data.sort((a,b) => a.price.localeCompare(b.price, undefined, {numeric: true}));
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```